# Calculating information flow using entropy - entropy is zero even for range?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Suppose we have an assignment $Y = X$ and that $X \in \{0,1,\dots,255\}$. Using **entropy**, I want to know how many bits of information passed in the assignment given that $Y > 80$.

If I state that $Y = 80$, I get that all $8$ bits of $X$ flowed into $Y$. On the other hand, if I state that $Y > 80$, I still get $8$ bits of flow,  since no matter what the following equation always holds

$$H(X|Y=j) = 0$$

When I calculate entropy, I get a sum of all $H(X|Y=j)$, which is still $0$, as follows

$$H(X|Y=0) p(Y=0) + H(X|Y=1) p(Y=1) + \cdots + H(X|Y=255) p(Y=255) = 0 + 0 + \cdots + 0 = 0$$

How is it possible if we don't know the exact value of $Y$ that the number of bits flowing is the same? I understand that the bits have passed into $Y$ but how do I take into account that fact that $Y$ is not a specific value in the case of $Y > 80$?

Comment: What are you assuming about probability mass functions?

Comment: I didn't assume anything. Just want to calculate the entropy

Comment: You have a perfect noiseless channel. I don't understand the question.

Comment: By the way, it's not a channel, it's just a code assignment. Anyway, the assumption that $Y > 80$ yields the same entropy as the assumption $Y = 80$. I know it makes sense but that fact that the exact value of Y is not given to us implies that maybe less bits of info flowed ?

Comment: No, i think i'm wrong. It's just weird that i get the same entropy for both $Y = 80$ and $Y > 80$ (which is a sum but a sum of zeros)

Comment: Well , suppose it's a code assignment (for example in C). Does it make sense the entropy is the same for both cases ?

Comment: Because mathematically it is the same